# FirebaseAuth fall back to last anonymously logged in user (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

A) User used my app, signed in with his Google+ account and created a bunch of data.

B) From another device he starts my app and uses the anonymous sign in method and creates a bunch of data.

So there are 2 accounts existing. A (google+) and B (anonymous)

Now he wants to login to his A account from B device.

My app now determines data conflict between data A and B.

I want to show a popup to the user which allows him to choose between:

1. Stay signed in with A and lose data B
2. Cancel sign in with A and fall back to B to keep data B

What do I have to store from the previous anonymous FirebaseUser/FirebaseAuth.getInstance() to reuse an anonymous session later?

Just doing `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();` again does create a new uid.

I also tried things like getting and reusing a token from: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getToken(true)`. but due to lack of JavaDoc and obfuscated code in the lib I am currently lost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for now I use this solution:

At first I try `linkWithCredential()` if that does not work, I show the popup and let user decide to stay signed in anonymoulsy or switch to existing account.